# Please solicit a comment on 'not an answer' flags

Tags: feature-request, not-an-answer

Over and over, discussions here end up with mods saying, 'don't use not an answer, use "other" so that you can explain the defect.'

Wouldn't it be superior to just let us add a comment to a 'not an answer' flag? To me, it engenders cognitive dissonance to have to think something like: 'oh, not an answer ... wait ... no, not an answer for a non-trivial reason ... click other and add a comment.'

If the comment box was available, I could fill it in when it made sense, and leave it empty when not.

Comment: Can we have one for the "invalid flag" flag on the 10K tools too, which can be similarly complicated to justify sometimes.

Comment: @Rosinante, in what ways would it be superior?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Edited to answer.

Answer (score 13):

"Not an answer" by itself is handy for obvious cases where someone posts "I have this problem too" or asks the OP for clarification in an answer. If you're flagging an answer because of a specific or a potentially non-obvious aspect (such as a broken link), then you're likely better off not using a built-in flag.

This holds true for any built-in flag reason, too.

Comment: I'm not trying to ask for a mandatory comment, but rather an optional one.

Comment: @Rosinante What's wrong with using the free-form, "needs moderator attention" box? The canned reasons are canned because they're meant to be used quickly for obvious cases. If it's not obvious, you shouldn't be using the canned reason.

Comment: @MarkTrapp If that's the consensus, I'll eventually reengineer my head. I started with the assumption that one should use the most specific relevant flag.

Comment: @MarkTrapp - the free form "needs attention" flags don't show up in the 10k tools at least.